# Dropped image preview in dropper plugin jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, drag-and-drop

I've been trying to make a drag and drop image field to upload to server using ajax. I've gone through some Jquery plugins and I found Dropper plugin can help.I tried like this.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="target"></div>
    <img>
```

**JS**

```
 $(".target").dropper({
        action: "upload.php",

    }).on("start.dropper", onStart);
    function onStart(e, files){
    console.log(files);
        $('.dropper-dropzone').css("background-color", "yellow");

        $('img').attr({src:files[0].name});
    }
```

But I failed to make a preview of dropped image on the dropper.
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/v8pqsczz/)

Comment: Can you please link the plugins you're using? a fiddle for that would be amazing in order to properly help you, despite it may be enough to append the image to the target div.

Comment: @briosheje http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/v8pqsczz/

Comment: @briosheje `$('img').attr({src:files[0].name});` it doesn't read the file from pc.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, console.log(files) is returning nothing. The documentation seems to be very poor, I'm looking forward directly in github to understand how this thing works.

Comment: I think you can get the files[0] once the upload is completed, therefore you should actually try to listen to "fileComplete.dropper" instead of "start.dropper".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tvshajeer i have made a image preview function who support both gecko & webkit browser if not then it send you the error message.

```
 image_preview(files[0].file).then(function(res){
        $('img').attr({src:res.data});
        });
```

Check out my answer on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/v8pqsczz/1/

Comment: I need to display image in that dropper field

Comment: Ohh sorry man i'm little bit confuse, hold for a while i'll try it once is it possible or not